# How to rotate values inside a cell in spreadsheet controlsfx when setting values from a list?

Tags: java, javafx, spreadsheet, controlsfx

[image]

I tried using  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998266/how-to-rotate-cell-value-in-spreadsheetview-controlsfx)  approach for the Name label and it worked great.

Now, I am trying to set values to other cells from a method using the code below:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("test1");
        values.add("test2");
        values.add("test3");
        values.add("test4");
        values.add("test2");
        values.add("test5we");
        values.add("test5we");
        values.add("test5we");
        values.add("test5qq");
        values.add("test5gf");
        values.add("test5v");
        values.add("test5s");
        values.add("test5a");

 for (int column = 3; column < values.size(); column++)
            grid.setCellValue(0, column, values.get(column));
```

I need to rotate the values inside the said cells.

Comment: @Maxoudela help plz

Comment: Just apply the same thing you did for the name. I don't understand where the issue is.. Please post a complete SSCCE( http://sscce.org/) code snippet if you want me to look in details

Comment: I am setting the value from a different method using the setCellValue. I cannot do the first approach there.